# Get KDE to run a bash script

Tags: bash, file, scripting, associations, kde-plasma

I have a bash script that takes a file name as an arg.  It works great from the command line.  When I right-click a file in KDE and select "open with", then point it to my script, it doesn't run.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `echo`-ing the arguments in the script to see what might be wrong.

Comment: What did you select in "Open with" dialog? Was it console?

Comment: I navigated to my bash script.

Comment: I forgot to add #!/bin/bash to the top of my script.  Rookie mistake.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your script relies on environment variables that get set by the terminal log in session. I don't know about KDE, but in Gnome, you can check "Open with Terminal" to ensure that the program is launched from a new Terminal session (with the same environment you'd get from ~/.bashrc). My suggestion is to add the following to the start of your script to ensure that it is being invoked:

```
  echo "I've been called: $@" > i_was_invoked.txt
```

And then, elsewhere in your script, you should put printf/echo statements to determine where it has gone awry. If you do that and post your script, it may be possible to assist you further.

Comment: I'd recommend using an absolute path with that output filename to make it easier to find.